# How to Access Twitter Hashtags Using Twitter API in a Flutter App?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am developing a Flutter app where I need to read and display Twitter hashtags. I've noticed several apps implement functionality that seems to interact with Twitter to fetch and display hashtag-related data. My goal is to integrate a similar feature in my Flutter app.

I am looking for guidance or suggestions on how to use the Twitter API within a Flutter environment to access hashtag data. Specifically, I'm interested in:

1. Is there an official or recommended Twitter API package for Flutter that I can use for this purpose?
2. What is the process for fetching hashtag data (e.g., trending hashtags, hashtag search) from Twitter within a Flutter app?
3. Are there any specific considerations or limitations I should be aware of when using the Twitter API in Flutter?

I am relatively new to using APIs in Flutter and any insights or resources on how to get started with the Twitter API in this context would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i want to read twitter posts in my application how do i do that ?

Answer (score 3):

The API does not depend on any technology or framework, so if it exists and others are using it in their apps, then you can use it in your app after reading the API pricing and license.

So yes, you can use it in Flutter, whether through an HTTP client or a wrapper package if exist.

Here you can find more info https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs

Comment: thanks, bro for your answer  can you vote my question please :)